# Como posso salvar uma lista ou exportar um objeto do tipo list no R?

Tags: r, lista

Tenho o um objeto do tipo list, semelhante a este que segue abaixo:

```
 x<- list(cod = 1:10, taxa = exp(-3:3), logico = c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE))
```

Qual a melhor forma de guardar este objeto, em *.R , *.csv ou _ _ _ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternativas utilizando funções do próprio R são:

Salvar como arquivo binário, que ocupa menos espaço, mas só poderá ser aberto no R.

```
save(x, file = "arquivo.RData")
save.image(file = "todoWorkspace.RData") # Salva todo workspace
```

Salvar como texto, mas que também só será legível no R, utilizando `dput`:

```
write(dput(x), file = "arquivo.txt")
```

Answer (score 3):

Você também pode salvar em formato `.rds`, ele é mais flexível do que o `.rda` no sentido de que você pode carregar a lista com o nome que você achar mais apropriado.

```
# salva lista x no arquivo x.rds
saveRDS(x, "x.rds")
# le lista mas com nome y agora
y <- readRDS("x.rds")
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando a função write.list() do pacote `erer`.

```
x<- list(cod = 1:10, taxa = exp(-3:3), logico = c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE))

library(erer)
write.list(x,file="caminhodoarquivo.R")
```

ou

```
write.list(x,file="caminhodoarquivo.csv")
```

Answer (score 2):

Além das demais alternativas, gosto também de salvar em um arquivo `.json`. Esse formato de arquivo tem se tornado padrão no compartilhamento de dados no formato de lista.

No R, é fácil salvar assim:

```
x<- list(cod = 1:10, taxa = exp(-3:3), logico = c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE))
library(jsonlite)
write(toJSON(x), file = "x.json")
```

O arquivo `x.json` é na verdade, um arquivo de texto com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
{
  "cod": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  "taxa": [0.0498, 0.1353, 0.3679, 1, 2.7183, 7.3891, 20.0855],
  "logico": [true, false, false, true]
}
```

Posteriormente, é possível ler o arquivo assim:

```
x <- fromJSON(txt = "x.json")
```